# What JavaScript, HTML, APIs are Google using in the World Cup Pin It Live Tool?

Tags: javascript, android, html, api, google-chrome

Google have just launched a new tool that "Pins" World Cup scores on Android. The Pin lives outside the browser. What Javascript APIs/HTML are they using to do this?

See example: 
https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/original_images/Game_Bubble_v1.gif

Comment: Interesting topic to be discussed!

Comment: Is that android chrome or the android google app?

Comment: I have noticed it on the Chrome Browser and Ghostery Browser